# sql where x = y and x = z and

Tags: sql, spring, spring-mvc, hql

@English isn't my first language.

I have a code (it's working) :

```
@Query("select new java.entity.dto.ProductsDTO(" +
        "p," +
        "count(c)," +
        "sum(case when c.user = :user then 1 else 0 end) > 0," +
        "sum(case when cart.user = :user then 1 else 0 end) > 0," +
        "sum(case when wish.user = :user then 1 else 0 end) > 0) " +
        "from Products p " +
        "left join p.commentaries c " +
        "left join p.carts cart " +
        "left join p.wishLists wish " +
        "left join p.tags tags " +
        "where p.categories = :categories " +
        "and tags.id in :tags " +
        "group by p,:user")
Page<ProductsDTO> findAllByCategoriesAndTags(Pageable pageable, @Param("categories") Categories categories, @Param("user") User user, @Param("tags") List<Long> tags);
```

As I read this part "tags.id = :tags " working like : 
"id = tag1 or id = tag2 or id = tag3 ...".

So, how can I write somt thing like this : "id1 = tag1 or id1 = tag2 and id2 = tag1 or id2 = tag2"

Comment: How can a variable be equal to several different things ?

Comment: my bad, I want to check array to array. like : 
"id1 = tag1 or id1 = tag2 and id2 = tag1 or id2 = tag2"
*update question*

Answer (score 0):

> As I read this part "tags.id = :tags " working like : "**id = tag1 or id = tag2 or id = tag3** ...".
>
> So, how can I write somt thing like this : "**id1 = tag1 or id1 = tag2 *and* id2 = tag1 or id2 = tag2**"

Simply append another `AND` statement after the already existing one :

```
    AND tags.id1 in :tags 
    AND tags.id2 in :tags
```

I assumed you meant "`(id1 = tag1 or id1 = tag2) and (id2 = tag1 or id2 = tag2)`". Be careful, though, about the fact that **AND** logical operations take precedence over **OR** ones. Without brackets, your expression would have been parsed as "`id1 = tag1 or (id1 = tag2 _and_ id2 = tag1) or id2 = tag2`"…